# Trouble with layer(geom="line") in ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I would like to plot a line chart in ggplot2. Here is how my data look like

```
query,trace,precision,recall
safe.order.q3.txt,rstr_oper_50000_100m,49.8406,24.9156
safe.order.q3.txt,sstr_cpu_50000_100m,49.774,24.8442
safe.order.q3.txt,sstr_oper_50000_100m,49.8735,24.885
safe.sem.q1.txt,ran_50000_100m,74.9204,24.8125
safe.sem.q1.txt,sys_50000_100m,58.1995,11.8975
safe.sem.q1.txt,rstr_cpu_50000_100m,75.6115,25.1855
safe.sem.q1.txt,rstr_oper_50000_100m,75.2262,24.9382
safe.sem.q1.txt,sstr_cpu_50000_100m,74.997,25.0963
safe.sem.q1.txt,sstr_oper_50000_100m,75.4195,25.3233
safe.sem.q2.txt,ran_50000_100m,78.6449,24.6323
safe.sem.q2.txt,sys_50000_100m,10.9353,0.255188
safe.sem.q2.txt,rstr_cpu_50000_100m,79.3762,24.6961
```

And here is the ggplot code that I store in the file `recprec.r`

```
w <- read.csv(file="../queryResults/comparison.100m.dat", head=TRUE, sep=",")
sem1 <- subset(w, query=="safe.sem.q1.txt")
p1 <- ggplot(data=sem1, aes(x=trace, y=precision)) + layer(geom="line") +     geom_text(aes(y=precision + .4, label=precision))
print(p1)
```

The execution of the code produce the following error and the char depicted in the image below where lines between values are not displayed

```
> source("recprec.r")
geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
```

[image]

What did I missed ?

Comment: What is your intention with the `color=` aes? Did you want some sort of multi-colored line? Normally a new color means a new line so since you've specified a new color for each new "Trace" value and "trace" is the x-axis, you have no connected points.

Comment: you're right, color doesn't matter here, let me edit my question.

Comment: Did you try replotting after that? Did that not change the plot? Are there lines now? (It's not easy to test since your sample data does not contain the column headers)

Comment: Removing the color in `aes` did not change anything. I've update my question to add the header in my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're plotting a categorical variable (factor) along the x-axis but you want to connect across categories, try explicitly setting a `group=` aesthetic.

```
ggplot(data=sem1, aes(x=trace, y=precision, group=query)) + 
    geom_line() + geom_text(aes(y=precision + .4, label=precision))
```